# Alternative for average when we have noise data?

Tags: normal-distribution, average

I am trying to get the average of some values, without letting the noises affect the result. For example, if the values were like this:

`4, 5, 3, 4, -85, 6, 3, 79, 3, 5, 3, -123, 4`

I would like to take the average of these values without considering the ones that are too far from the majority. In the above case, values `-85, 79, -123` are very different than the others and I don't want them to affect the final average. So the average should be:

`(4+5+3+4+6+3+3+5+3+4) / 10 = 4`

Is there a way to do this? I thought about taking an estimate **Majority** or **Gaussian Model**, but I am not sure.

Note: I *don't* want the resulting average to be precise. Just a good estimate is enough.

Comment: If the noise is not too frequent you could look for the median.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri the problem is the noise can be frequent and affect the average in a bad way. Is there a way to completely ignore the noise data?

Comment: I meant the median, not the average.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri you are right. That's better than average. But what about **normal distribution** or some other distribution? Would that work better in this case?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I mean if the real data values are very close to each other and the noises are far from them, by calculating the normal distribution, maybe it is possible to ignore the noises and say all this data is representing some value around `4`.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not sure I understood.

Comment: like if there were 1000 numbers in `[1 10]` such that: **400** of them around `3`, **580** of them around `9`, and the remaining **20** are noise. Can a mixture of gaussian models help to ignore the noises and say the right number is either `3` or `9`?

Comment: Take a look at [robust statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics), of which the median is an example.